# JQuery UI Datepicker Thai Buddhist Year

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using jquery-1.11.0 and jquery-ui datepicker to achieve a dropdown datepick on my textfield.

However, for Thailand, there is something call the Buddhist year which adds 543 to our current phyiscal year. How can I achieve this with the jquery datepicker? I have tried the follow sites but due to different jquery version, it seems to have a weird behaviour.

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-datepicker-extension-buddhist-era/

http://www.anassirk.com/articles/1

http://keith-wood.name/calendarsPickerRef.html

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is fairly trivial with leveraging the datepicker's `yearSuffix` option, which allows you to insert unescaped html. Something like:

In stylesheet:

```
.ui-datepicker-year { display:none; }
```

In `onChangeMonthYear`:

```
inst.settings.yearSuffix = year + 543;
```

[See jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/k76Ra/)

Disclaimer: At some point someone will probably realize what a terrible idea it is to append unescaped html to your widget's titlebar, and this will become unusable. Should be fine for 1.11.0/1.10.4.

Disclaimer2: I know absolutely nothing about Buddhist years. This simply changes the *visible* `year` to `year+543`. **It handles absolutely no corner cases**